# Graphql with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, graphql

I am trying to use jmeter to Automate graphql API testing. I have done the manual testing with postman. However, since some one suggested i am trying to automate with jmeter. unfortunately i am new to API testing itself and having great difficulties.

As i understand Graphql method only deals with POST, but in my Jmeter it is throwing an error, but when i change it to GET, i get 200 ok response.

Also in the body data i am directly entered the graphQL query is this correct.
In the return response data i don get any information related to my query.

I have added header manager with

```
Content-type = "Application/json"
Accept-encoding
Authorization
Accept
Connection
```

My graphql query is

```
query{cmCases(filters: {caseId:"case-6"})
 {
    items {
      id

    }
  }
}
```

In the response i am just receiving meta data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking into [HTTP Methods, Headers, and Body](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#http-methods-headers-and-body) chapter of the GraphQL documentation GraphQL supports both GET and POST methods so you can choose whatever you want or whatever you need
2. Looking into [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) documentation chapter header values are case-sensitive so you need to change `Application/json` to `application/json` in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)
3. Given you can successfully execute request in Postman you should be able to record this request by JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with upcoming JMeter 5.3.1 or 5.4 you’ll be able to use the GraphQL Http Request.

Until it is released you can try a nightly build:

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/jmeter/nightlies/

See:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/627

[image: GraphQL query]